# Reset Cache TTL in each Access

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, caching, laravel-5.8, laravel-cache

I was wondering if there is any way to update cache TTL from the last time it has accessed?

currently, I have a method to login to adobe connect with API call and API session is valid for 4 days from the last call.
but my cache driver only keeps session in the cache for 4 days from the moment that is added. but I want to keep it for 4 days since the last time it has accessed!

is there any way to update Cache TTL? 
I'm sure forgetting and reinserting key is not best practice.

```php
    /**
     * Login Client Based on information that introduced in environment/config file
     *
     * @param Client $client
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function loginClient(Client $client)
    {
        $config = $this->app["config"]->get("adobeConnect");

        $session = Cache::store($config["session-cache"]["driver"])->remember(
            $config['session-cache']['key'],
            $config['session-cache']['expire'],
            function () use ($config, $client) {
                $client->login($config["user-name"], $config["password"]);
                return $client->getSession();
            });

        $client->setSession($session);
    }
```

Comment: You can't update TTL only. you need to update the whole cache item with new TTL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen for the event [CacheHit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#events), test for the key pattern, and reset the cache for that key with a new TTL.

To do that, you should create a new listener and add it to the `EventServiceProvider`:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Cache\Events\CacheHit' => [
        'App\Listeners\UpdateAdobeCache',
    ]
];
```

And the listener:

```
class UpdateAdobeCache {

    public function handle(CacheHit $event)
    {
        if ($event->key === 'the_cache_key') { // you could also test for a match with regexp
            Cache::store($config["session-cache"]["driver"])->put($event->key, $event->value, $newTTL);
        }
    }
}
```